# Error: unable to attach bpf program, lirc device name was not found

Tags: lirc

Hi I am trying to run the command: sudo ir-keytable -v -t -p all but I get the error in posted. Also, I get "Protocols for device can not be changed". This is to test the input run for the ir remote I want to use for my project. I have successfully installed the ir-keytable. I am using raspberry pi 4B. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Raspberry OS were you using? I am having the a similar issue with **ir-keytable** on Bookworm. I have configured gpio-ir in **/boot/firmware/config.txt**

```
tail -1 /boot/firmware/config.txt
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=25
```

The hardware and wiring is proven as the same configuration has been with Bullseye and works perfectly.

```
sudo ir-keytable -v -t -p  rc-5,rc-5-sz,jvc,sony,nec,sanyo,mce_kbd,rc-6,sharp,xmpir-keytable
Found device /sys/class/rc/rc1/
Found device /sys/class/rc/rc2/
Found device /sys/class/rc/rc0/
Couldn't find any node at /sys/class/rc/rc0/lirc*.
Input sysfs node is /sys/class/rc/rc0/input0/
Event sysfs node is /sys/class/rc/rc0/input0/event0/
Parsing uevent /sys/class/rc/rc0/input0/event0/uevent
/sys/class/rc/rc0/input0/event0/uevent uevent MAJOR=13
/sys/class/rc/rc0/input0/event0/uevent uevent MINOR=64
/sys/class/rc/rc0/input0/event0/uevent uevent DEVNAME=input/event0
Parsing uevent /sys/class/rc/rc0/uevent
/sys/class/rc/rc0/uevent uevent NAME=rc-cec
/sys/class/rc/rc0/uevent uevent DRV_NAME=cec
/sys/class/rc/rc0/uevent uevent DEV_NAME=vc4-hdmi-0
input device is /dev/input/event0
/sys/class/rc/rc0/protocols protocol cec (enabled)
Opening /dev/input/event0
Input Protocol version: 0x00010001
Protocols for device can not be changed
Error: unable to attach bpf program, lirc device name was not found
Testing events. Please, press CTRL-C to abort
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133212)

Answer (score 0):

The second problem in this post is **SOLVED**.
I upgraded the kernel to Linux bookworm32 6.1.65-v8+ by running:
`sudo rpi-update`
After a reboot the IR remote control worked perfectly. Also remember that the dtoverlay must be added to **/boot/firmware/config.txt** and not to /boot/config.txt